# Can I format a link to show/hide certain elements upon page load?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, hyperlink

I have a page on which there are elements that can be shown/hidden with jquery:

```
<div id="hide">HIDE</div>
<div id="show">SHOW</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#show").hide();
  $("#hide").hide();
  $("#hide").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#show").show();
  });
  $("#show").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#hide").show();
  });
</script>
```

**route:**

```
get "static/showhide" => "static#showhide", :as => :showhide_static
```

So when I link to the page with `showhide_static_path`, the page loads with both divs hidden. Is there a way I can control which div is hidden and which is shown based on the link I write?

One idea I had was doing something like this:

```
<% if @x == true %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#show").hide();
  </script>
<% elsif @y == true %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#show").hide();
  </script>
<% end %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#hide").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#show").show();
  });
  $("#show").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#hide").show();
  });
</script>
```

Is there a way I can set the value of `@x` or `@y` based on the syntax of the link?

Comment: Maybe use some php?   Set up your links with GET strings, and have php extract the GET data, put the values into a hidden div somewhere.   Then you could read it from JavaScript and show/hide your divs based on the value of the variable.

Comment: no idea what you're trying to do, and the code is too messy to guess what is intended, also @MichaelPodrybau this is a ruby on rails question, adding php would be adding an extra layer and making more mess

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady I'm just asking if there is a way to control the jquery that gets executed on the page I'm linking to, based on how I write the link.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady If I could set an instance variable in the link somehow, then I could use `if` statements with that variable to selectively execute the jquery.

Comment: instead of doing so many if/else on ruby level, i would set a variable in the javascript through ruby and make the javascript follow it's logic

Comment: But can I set a variable for the page I am linking to?

Comment: You can handle visibility of your divs during rendering template on the basis of some condition, no need to do it in your js code after page will finish loading

Comment: @rubykid How can I control the visibility?

Comment: Is there any strong reason to check syntax of the link?

Comment: Well I'm going to have a table of contents, and if you click on a certain element in the table of contents, the relevant paragraph is shown and the others hidden. I want to be able to write a link that shows a certain paragraph _on page load_, so the user doesn't have to click on the table of contents link.

Comment: For example, if there are links for "intro" and "chapter 1", I want to be able to write two seperate links that render the page with the intro paragraph shown and chapter 1 paragraph hidden, and vice versa, respectively.

Comment: @JoeMorano <div id='hide' class="#{'hidden' if some_condition}">HIDE</div>

Comment: @rubykid But how can I set that condition when I'm linking to the page?

Comment: @JoeMorano not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: The div is either shown or hidden based on some condition. But how can I write two seperate links that set different conditions? In other words, I want one link to show item 1 and hide item 2, and the other link to show item2 and hide item1.

Comment: How you will decide what show and what not? What the condition?

Comment: Let's say if `@x == true`, `item1` is shown and `item2` is hidden. If `@x == false`, `item2` is shown and `item1` is hidden. How could I write a link that sets `@x` either to true or false?

Comment: I'm totally can't understand why link must initialize local variable with some value, my apologize :) let me explain my point of view in next comment

Comment: We have a template with some html, there we have two divs. We conditionally set classes of this divs so one of them is hidden, another visible. We render this template and send html to the browser. After page loaded we bind events  in our js code so when we click on divs they will hide/show. What I miss?

Comment: @rubykid I want to be able to write two seperate links, `link1` and `link2`. When I follow `link1`, it should render the page, but `item1` should be hidden, while `item2` is shown. When I follow `link2`, it should render the same page, but `item2` should be hidden, while `item1` is shown. So you see, the two different links cause different behavior, even though they both link to the same page. If I could set an instance variable in the link, it would solve my problem.

Comment: What I trying to say: no need to hide both divs in js as you do it here $("#show).hide(); $("#hide).hide(); Just send them from backend in appropriate state.

Comment: @rubykid How can I do that?

Comment: When you talking about render you mean the full request cycle or just manipulating with DOM without page reloading?

Comment: @rubykid It's a full request cycle.

Comment: You can send conditionals you needed via params. Wait a minute I show you how.

Comment: link1 might be as this: <a href="/index?condition=condition1">Index page</a> then in your index_controller @condition = params[:condition] and in your index.html.erb <div id='hide' class="#{@condition == condition1 ? 'hidden' : 'visible'}">HIDE</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass params via the query string like this: `example.com/static/showhide?x=1&y=0`. Then you can access these using the params hash, example: `params[:x]`.

Another way to do this is using purely javascript and url fragments. For example: `example.com/static/showhide#1`. To access this form javascript: `window.location.hash`

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Bonus tips:

- You don't need to do `<% if @x == true %>` you can just do `<% if @x %>`.
- You might wanna give your variables more meaningful names.